# Salto de linea FS node?

Tags: nodejs

estoy creando un archivo con FS, con ciertos textos que voy obteniendo de un array. Se esta creando bien ,solo que necesito que cada iteracion sea un salto de linea

Codigo:

```js
const data = [{...},{...},{...}]

// Variables para el FS
const timestamp: string  = moment().utc(true).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
const pathFolder: string = `assets/carpeta/${timestamp}`
const pathFile:string = `${pathFolder}/archivo.txt')}`
 
const creando = promisify(fs.mkdirSync);
const agregando = promisify(fs.appendFile);

 for (const dia of data) {
      const texto:string = `${dia.accountBalance};${dia.totalAccount};${cbu};${dia.balancecbu}` 

      try {
        // Creamos el folder para el archivo si es que no existe
        if (!fs.existsSync(pathFolder)){
          await creando(pathFolder,{recursive:true})
        }

        // Insertamos la linea al 
        await agregando(pathFile,texto,{encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a'})

      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error al crear el folder o file',error);
      }
  }
```

Como les digo, el archivo se crea bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no salta de linea por cada iteracion, deberia quedar:

0;0;15154555151;950001

2;15154555151;10000

Answer (score 1):

Agrega el salto de linea directamente al final `\n`:

```
const texto:string = `${dia.accountBalance};${dia.totalAccount};${cbu};${dia.balancecbu}\n`
```